# Are there any standard techniques and/or examples of collapsing multiple events in Java?

Tags: java, events, user-interface, event-handling

Let me first sketch the concrete situation I find myself in, although my question is actually more general. I'm writing a component containing several sliders and I have listeners listening for events from these sliders. When one of these sliders changes I want my component to send an event to its own listeners to notify them that its state has changed. I would however like to limit the number of events that are sent, i.e. if there are several events waiting when my component notifies its listeners, I would like to collapse all these events into a single event.

My question is whether there are standard techniques for this. If so, any example would be welcome, because I couldn't find any. (Maybe collapsing is not the correct terminology?)

Comment: You need to have idea of how close together they need to be that you want to group them. i.e. The user is unlikely to update the sliders more than once per second, so how long would you want to wait to group multiple updates into one?

Comment: Users changing the sliders isn't really an issue. I'm more concerned about a programmatic change. I'm really taking about just collapsing all events that are waiting to be handled in the queue at the moment that my components starts handling the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe *collapsing* is the correct term. An example class from the Java Core libraries that implements such behavior is [`RepaintManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RepaintManager.html). I would check out it's [source code](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/swing/javax/swing/RepaintManager.java.htm) to see how it collapses multiple repaint requests.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do any such thing you should make sure that it is really necessary.

I guess you would need to access the EventQueue from your listener.  When an event triggers the callback method, this method should first look in the queue to see if there are more recent events of the relevant type and, if so, process the most recent event only and then remove all events of that type from the queue.

Since the callbacks are always on the Swing (awt) event thread, you don't need to worry about concurrency.